# Remove workspaces and build controller settings from TFS backup

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, backup, workspace

There are two TFS servers. We need to move data from first server to second server. We need to move all data else workspaces and build controller settings. But if to do backup of first TFS server, then it contains these data too....

Is there some way to remove workspaces and build controller settings from TFS backup (before it will be restored to second server)?

Thanks to Richard, I will specify the question: did somebody manage to find the set of sql commands for to delete from backup database (yes, TFS2010) the data about workspaces and build controller settings and break nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to remove workspaces and build controller settings from TFS backup (before it will be restored to second server)?

I'm fairly confident that the answer is, unfortunately, No.

TFS backup (including backup to restore on another server) is at the database level, and that is where all the state is held. To move only part of the data would require moving only part of the database<sup>1</sup>.

It is quite possible to use the command line to enumerate and delete workspaces (see [`tf workspace /delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28VS.80%29.aspx)) of other users from account with sufficient access.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or database*s* is using TFS 2005 or 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of your first TFS. Then delete all workspaces & try to enforce default Build configuration. Then make a second backup.

Restore this second backup to your second TFS. Then restore the first backup in your first TFS.

I have never done such actions, but I would research on how to do them if I was in your place. The alternative:

> did somebody manage to find the set of sql commands for to delete from
>   backup database (yes, TFS2010) the data about workspaces and build
>   controller settings and break nothing?

would require a true TFS Kung Fu master to perform.

Comment: Thanks for advise, pantelif! But unfortunately operations with removing of workspaces, changing of build configuration and restoring of backup on first TFS server take a while. We don't have a possibility to stop server on such time...